# Ensuring that the given image is flipped of another one

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have two images, one is the mirrored (flipped) one of another. I am using surf object for detection. I want to find out that one image is mirrored of another. How can i achieve this? Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: If you suspect one image is flipped, there's no need for SURF, just un-flip and compare.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot. But when i don't know the state of my image, then how can i achieve?

Comment: You can try some ideas from MI-SIFT: mirror and inversion invariant generalization for SIFT descriptor http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1816076 . But is seems much easier just trying flipped and unflipped images.

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the image with the filpped and unflipped Version should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Flip and compute some kind of [cross-correlation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate) value. If the image is the same, the correlation must be high (equivalently, the sum of square differences must be low).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach in this case is to calculate the histograms of the two images and match them. It will work even if the image has been both resized and flipped.